# Plugin crashes on refreshing page from app on Win 7

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, windows-7, silverlight-oob, silverlight-plugin

I have a page with Silverlight 4 oob app. After app is installed the bage on the page should automatically refresh. 
I tried calling the scripts or simple Document.Submit from code on InstallStateChanged  - and they all worked well on win XP (not only on my machine), but on Win 7 or Vista the page hangs or even silverlight plugin crashes before the installation beginning. However without refresh function on the installation process flows smoothly. 
How should I do the correct refresh for those systems? The info why this can happen will be helpful too.

```
    public App ()
    {
        this.Startup += this.Application_Startup;
        this.Exit += this.Application_Exit;
        this.UnhandledException += this.Application_UnhandledException;

        InitializeComponent();

        App.Current.InstallStateChanged += (s, c) => HtmlPage.Document.Submit(); //used that as the most common used example
    }

    private void Application_Startup (object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Application.Current.IsRunningOutOfBrowser)
        {
            this.RootVisual = new MainPage();
        } else if (Application.Current.InstallState == InstallState.Installed)
        {
            this.RootVisual = new InstalledPage();
        } else
        {
            this.RootVisual = new InstallPage();
        }
    }
```

Where MainPage and installedPage are simple grids with text field. Install Page contains only button with click event - to install the App. The web page is auto generated one. Nothing more. Still on Win 7 and Vista have the same prob while install as they had.

UPD: [project files](http://www.mediafire.com/?p7815nbn941o4ba)

Comment: Create new project that reproduce the problem and show it to us. This way will be much more easier to help you...

Comment: @Ai_boy, that project will contain App.cs file only :) What do you suppose to get?

Comment: We expect to get the App.cs, MainPage.xaml, MainPage.xaml.cs, a .csproj and a .sln, all in a zip file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have changed your test case like this:

```
public App () {
        ...

    App.Current.InstallStateChanged += new EventHandler(Current_InstallStateChanged);
}

void Current_InstallStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if(App.Current.InstallState == System.Windows.InstallState.Installed) {
        HtmlPage.Document.Submit();
    }
}
```

And it refreshes upon install on windows 7 fine.

Comment: Thanks! The answer was simple indeed.